# Rolling deployment of Play Framework webapp on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework, port, updates, amazon-ecr

I want to deploy a Play web application on AWS ECS. I have created a cluster of 2 EC2 instances running the web service. Each instance is running a single task. The cluster is load balanced by an AWS ELB.

Upon pushing the new docker image to the repository I create a new revision of my task definition which includes the new image tagged with `latest`. When I update the service to use the new task definition then all of the EC2 instances are updating their task immediately. Even though I have 2 EC2 instances I experience a downtime because AWS updates all instances at the same time, instead of updating one instance after the other in a rolling deployment kind of way.

I tried to launch more than one task on each EC2 instance, but this is obviously not possible since each task requires Play's default port 9000 and I get a "port already in use" error message in the events tab of the service.

I can think of two possible solutions:

- Each task instance uses a dynamic port instead of the default port. (How can I configure a load balancer to "search" for the dynamic ports?)
- Create two separate ECR clusters, have them both in a single load balancer target group and manually change the task definition of the second cluster after the first has finished updating. (How can this be automated - or can it be automated at all?)

Is one of these solutions the way to go or are there any other solutions or best practices for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the sources of the problem.
First of all I mixed up the terminology a bit. The docs for AWS Elastic Beanstalk explain the [difference between a rolling update and a rolling deployment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.rollingupdates.html#environments-cfg-rollingupdates-deployments). I was trying to achieve a rolling deployment, not a rolling update - I will edit my question accordingly.

In addition I noticed that I changed the "Minimum healthy percent" of instances and inadvertently saved the settings at 0%. Therefore ECS correctly took the liberty and redeployed more than one EC2 instance at the same time, leaving no healthy instances on my cluster. I found a very helpful video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XN_8Lbth8xs) where the author goes through the process of upgrading the ECS cluster and then downgrading it again. Everything works as expected now.